# how to set specific part of the image to white and remaining part to black in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to learn image processing and I just found one question related to my area of interest. I have an image in which there is two things one is mug and the other is thermos. I just want to show the cup in white color for that first i convert the image in graysacle and then I convert with `imbinarize`. This is my problem statement

Example 1

The original image on the left is given i.e., original.jpg. The middle image (theft 1) shows that mug is stolen from the original image. Now you have to generate the output in such a way that the stolen object i.e., the mug is visible only. The rightmost image shows the stolen object i.e., mug, that is the required output to be generate by your code.

This is an image the kind of output I want

[image]

This is my code for that

```
close all
I = imread('Original-min-min.JPG');
gray = rgb2gray(I)
BW = imbinarize(gray);
% Display the original image next to the binary version.
 figure
 imshowpair(gray,BW,'montage')
       
     [r,c] = size(BW);
     for i=1:r
         for j=1:c
             f=BW(i,j);
             if f>127 && f<256 
                 BW(i,j)=255;
             end
         end
     end
     figure
     imshow(BW)
```

This is the output of my code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WVYM.png)
how to set black everything except cup i want the output like  i upload the picture before

Comment: There is no question here so far, only a problem statement. Can you ask specifically what you want help with?

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. -- your task appears to describe *taking per-pixel differences* and thresholding on that.